# Passing multiple values to same parameter with a PHP array with CURL

Tags: php, rest, curl, post

I'm need to execute a REST API POST request with PHP.

The URL post parameters looks like this and works fine when executed as such:

```
https://example.com.json?userid=MYUSER&key=MYKEY&order=000000&server=ns1.example.com&server=ns2.example.net&server=ns3.example.net
```

I use the following PHP array with success before without any issues for passing unique values to the same API in my PHP Curl Request:

```
$data = array(
'userid' => 'value',
'key' => 'value',
'order' => 'value',
);
```

The problem now, looking at the URL is that the "server" parameters accepts more than one value (order is not important) and I'm supposed to pass this as an string of arrays, minimum of 2 values.

But this does not work:

```
$data = array(
'userid' => 'value',
'key' => 'value',
'order' => 'value',
'server' => array('ns1.example.net','ns2.example.net')
);
```

I tried multiple different ways. How do I pass multiple values to the same parameter on that array?

Comment: Depends on how the API server is written. PHP does not innately support URLs with repeated parameters like `foo=1&foo=2&foo=3`. If you want to pass multiple values for a single parameter, you would generally use the array syntax `foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3`, which your second attempt should have accomplished. I'm not sure you can emulate the former (which seems to be required for your odd API server) with PHP's curl functions, you'd probably have to build out the URL string yourself.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed a very strange and old API. 

The docs are here:

https://manage.resellerclub.com/kb/node/776

Building the URL manually works fine but I was trying to have consistent clean code with all requests. Why do they use the same parameter is beyond me. Never saw that in any API. NS is supposed to be an array of strings in that documentation.

Comment: Post the code you use to build the curl request from the `$data` array.

Comment: // Call the API
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1); //0 for a get request
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,3);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 35);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    die('Unable to connect: ' . curl_errno($ch) . ' - ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close ($ch);

Comment: How are you building `$url`?

Comment: $url = "https://httpapi.com/api/domains/modify-ns.json";

Just the URL, I then pass all the POST parameters from the array. But only this specific parameter is giving me issues. I guess its building the http query correctly. If I use the full URL it works fine but have to pass everything manually.

Comment: You will have to write your own version of http_build_query() that outputs `foo=1&foo=2` instead of `foo[]=1&foo[]=2`.

Comment: Thanks, so the problem is indeed with the http_build_query then. I suspected that. Maybe someone can suggest a better method for CURL requests that I can use to replace http_build_query. That works with POST, GET, PUT, etc. And lets me fill just the values and reuse the same code.

Comment: Another way could be removing the %5B0%5D values from the created URL by http_build_query, I guess there is no way around sadly without changing how it builds the query.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty simple and should work just fine as long as you're sure there are no other legit instances of `[]` in the values you're passing.